# Google Cloud Run Java SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to launch a service on Google Cloud Run via code in Java.

The project I believe I need to use is the [java-servicedirectory](https://github.com/googleapis/java-servicedirectory) (and associated [JavaDoc](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-servicedirectory/latest/index.html)). I made that assumption based on looking through the [Run REST API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest).

What I am attempting to replicate is the CLI command of:

```
gcloud run deploy mytest \
  --image=us.gcr.io/{project}/{image}:{tag} \
  --allow-unauthenticated \
  --platform=managed \
  --region=us-central1 \
  --project={project}
```

I tried using the [CreateServiceRequest](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-servicedirectory/latest/com/google/cloud/servicedirectory/v1beta1/CreateServiceRequest.html) object to accomplish this but I haven't had any luck.

Does anyone have any links to examples I can look through to help figure this out? I did not see anything else in the [GitHub repository for Google APIs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) that appears to be specific to the Run configuration.

As always:  thanks!

---

**Update**:  found [this project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-run-button/) and I am trying to replicate it in Java.

Currently getting this while attempting to describe an already deployed service:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Could not parse parent name: namespaces/{project}/services/mytest
```

Comment: Replicating the command that launches a Cloud Run service is fairly complicated. To see the API requests and data structures, add the command line option `--log-http` to the CLI command.

Comment: @JohnHanley That's incredibly useful.

I see the proper URL just for the GET request, which is `https://{region}-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/{project}/services/mytest?alt=json`

I am going to work on just replicating that using the GCP libraries to see what I can do.

Comment: I might wind up delegating to the command line and install `gcloud` via the `Dockerfile` for now.

Comment: Do you need more help on this? An example? You have also the [gcloud sdk mirror](https://github.com/twistedpair/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/third_party/apis/run/v1/run_v1_client.py) that you can see to understand the calls.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere that's helpful, too. My workaround for now is going to be to setup something that calls the GCloud command line through a protected REST API and then migrate to figuring out the solution at this point. I have a time crunch for a POC and that will get me over the hump until I make a more formal/elegant solution.

Comment: Not really great to bind your code with system dependencies. And it won't work on Cloud Functions or App Engine for example. Keep us posted if you need more.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I 100% agree, but this is just for a proof-of-concept. This isn't for production deploy yet. When I finally get it figured out I'll put it in a Google Cloud Function, but for now I'm just going to run it in a basic VM to get over the hurdle.